# How can I keep the data in my textbox (WP)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am working on an APP that can take number from user and send message to that number.

The number is saved in global variable, the number is changeable by the user. I want the phone number to appear in the textbox every time the user opens the app, so he/she can view the number and update it if they require.

**What I've tried:**

```
phonenumber.Text = (App.Current as App).phoneglobal;
```

I added it  after `InitializeComponent();`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you saving the phone number anywhere when you close the app, or are you only saving it into a global variable?

Comment: why wpf & wpf-controls? tag your question properly. What version of wp? WP7/WP8/WP8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using WPF, I recommend using the [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx). In your case, you would have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private App currentApp = (Application.Current as App);

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return currentApp.phoneglobal;
        }
        set
        {
            currentApp.phoneglobal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PhoneNumber"));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your xaml, simply bind to the ViewModel's `PhoneNumber` property.

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow">
    <TextBox x:Name="phonenumber" Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" />
</Window>
```

Then you should never need to set `phonenumber.Text` from the code-behind. If you need to set the phone number programmatically, set `viewModel.PhoneNumber` and the text box will automatically update.

Note that if you set `currentApp.phoneglobal` directly (without using `viewModel.PhoneNumber`), then the text box will NOT automatically update.

If this doesn't help, post your xaml code as well as any references in code to the `phonenumber` text box.